# how to order CSS elements?

Tags: html, css, position, z-index

I'm having trouble getting a menu to appear on top of other elements on a page. The sample page code is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/JdUTG/13/

Any ideas on what CSS properties I can use to get the menu to always be on top?

the menu is from here:
http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/cssplay-click-click.html

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at it now: http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/JdUTG/5/

You had `z-index = -1;` instead of `z-index: -1;`. Just a  mistype.

Comment: thanks that worked for that case, but I realized it isn't what I wanted. I updated the code, but z-index: -1; won't work anymore.

Comment: Add this: `position: relative; z-index: 1;` to `#testMenu` . Take a look http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/JdUTG/15/